# How to set a repository to watch for releases only using either gh or the rest api

Tags: github, github-api, watch

I've been searching the rest API and gh but can't seem to find the right API call or cli options to do this.

Basically would be nice to run
gh watch release only repo_url

Has anyone figured this out?